# Change TileServer in pgAdmin used by geometry viewer

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, geometry, viewer

Having exhausted other search options, I was hoping someone might know of a way to change the pgAdmin geometry viewer default tile server?  It tries to bring up the OSM one, but we are behind a firewall and it cannot be accessed. However, we have an internal one that could be used. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tile servers are hardcoded in [web/pgadmin/static/js/sqleditor/geometry_viewer.js](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=pgadmin4.git;a=blob;f=web/pgadmin/static/js/sqleditor/geometry_viewer.js;hb=HEAD#l110).

In an installed pgAdmin, you can find this file in a minified form in `.../web/pgadmin/static/js/generated/sqleditor.js`; search for "tile.openstreetmap.org".

If you cannot edit that file, then you might be able to configure your internal DNS to redirect `a|b|c.tile.openstreetmap.org` to your own server.

Comment: Found the file and was able to modify it to point to our OSM tile server. Thanks very much!

Comment: in addition to @CL. answer, in **pgAdmin 4 v6.21** you have to change the tile server URL that also existed in 
`.../web/pgadmin/static/js/generated/app.bundle.js`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the pre-packaged version (rather than building it from source after making changes), you may need to make changes to the generated file under `web/pgadmin/static/js/generated/sqleditor.js` instead.

This was tested on pgAdmin 5.7, paths may have changed in more recent versions (e.g. 6.x)